# The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. Hitting URL on IE and then calling through web service fixes it

Tags: wcf, ssl-certificate

I am trying to call a WCF web service from my .net application which is a web api. I get the error below:

The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

This error is seen until I open IE on the same server where my web api is hosted through IIS, and then I browse to the WCF service URL, it prompts me with the certificate name that I have for the WCF service in my trusted certificate store. Once I click OK on the certificate popup in IE, it goes successfully to the wsdl of the service. After that if I make a call from my webapi it proceeds successfully. But every day it fails until I do that. I know there is something wrong with my certificate setup, but I am not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.